# django cant use global variable in class based view

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

my view is like this

```
class RecordView(View):
    record_form = RecordForm
    record_files = {}
    templare = 'acquisition.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        fil = urllib.urlopen('/home/student/wwww.jpg')
        self.record_files = {'small_cover': SimpleUploadedFile('hehe.jpg', fil.read())}
        rr_form = self.record_form()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'rr_form': rr_form,
                                            })
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        record = RecordForm(request.POST, self.record_files)
        record.save()
        HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Here i have populated self.record_files in get method.. but after i post data i see self.record_files as empty dictionary. I get confused here. What can  i do to do so.

Comment: Should you not be doing `request.POST, request.FILES` instead?

Comment: here i have to save files dynamically not from the files posted from form. If we are posting from form we will be using request.FILES

Answer (score 3):

The state of your view instance is not maintained between a get and a post, so setting `record_files` on the instance will not keep it for the next request. You would need to put that logic in the `dispatch` method, or store information in the user's `session`.

```
class RecordView(View):
    record_form = RecordForm
    record_files = {}
    templare = 'acquisition.html'

    # dispatch is called before deciding whether to use get() or post()
    # so any instance-level properties that require the request can go here.
    # This could even go in __init__().
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        fil = urllib.urlopen('/home/student/wwww.jpg')
        self.record_files = {'small_cover': SimpleUploadedFile('hehe.jpg', fil.read())}
        return super(RecordView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        rr_form = self.record_form()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'rr_form': rr_form,
                                        })

    # self.record_files will be available in a get, or a post (or any valid 
    # method for that matter).
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        record = RecordForm(request.POST, self.record_files)
        record.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: when i do so adding a dispatch method, I get the ValueError saying RecordView is returning None instead of HttpResponse Object

Comment: will you plese make me clear about dispatch.. i really cant figure out

Comment: My mistake, `dispatch` should *return* the super.

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly how it suppose to work. Whenever you have a GET request, it will call method `get`, and if it is a POST request, naturally it will call `post` method, but not the `get` method. So here is how you can solve your problem:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class RecordView(TemplateView):
    record_form = RecordForm
    record_files = {}
    template_name = 'acquisition.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **context):
        fil = urllib.urlopen('/home/student/wwww.jpg')
        self.record_files = {
            'small_cover': SimpleUploadedFile('hehe.jpg', fil.read())
        }
        context.update({
            'record_files': self.record_files,
            'rr_form': self.record_form()
        })
        fil.close()
        return super(RecordView, self).get_context_data(**context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        record_form = self.record_form(request.POST, self.record_files)
        if record_form.is_valid():
             record_form.save()
        ## or do a redirect instead, like you had before:
        # return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        context['rr_form'] = record_form
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```